# Where is TeXfont in TeX Live 2012?

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, context

All of the font installation instructions in the ConTeXt Wiki say to use TeXfont.

To my great despair, I can't seem to access TeXfontin my TeX Live installation on Windows. Given that I've installed all of the packages from TeXfont, how else should I install fonts into TeX Live 2012?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong. Looking at other pages I find (Building the Font Database) [http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX#How_LuaTeX_handles_system_fonts]

Comment: You don't need texfont if you use LuaTeX. To use a font, simply follow the instructions you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

It's a perl script called `texfont.pl` belonging to ConTeXt. On my TeX Live 2012 installation it's in the `scripts` subdirectory:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/context/perl/texfont.pl
```

Further resources on how to use it:

- [TeXfont](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TeXfont) in the ConTeXt wiki
- The [TeXfont](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mtexfont.pdf) manual
- [A Beginner's Adventures with TeXfont](http://lindsay.at/files/tex/TexfontExamined.pdf) by Adam Lindsay
- [texfont man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/texfont)